# Defining instance for Num

Tags: haskell

I have a module with type declaration and some functions for this type

```
module Stream where

import Prelude ((+), (-), (<), (++), (*), otherwise, id)
import qualified Prelude as P

infixr 1 :&


data Stream a = a :& Stream a


instance P.Show a => P.Show (Stream a) where
  show xs = showInfinity (P.show (take 5 xs)) where
    showInfinity xs = P.init xs ++ "..."

head :: Stream a -> a
head (x:&_) = x


tail :: Stream a -> Stream a
tail (_:&xs) = xs


(!!) :: Stream a -> P.Int -> a
(!!) xs 0 = head xs
(!!) xs n = (tail xs) !! (n - 1)


take :: P.Int -> Stream a -> [a]
take 0 xs = []
take n xs = (head xs) : (take (n - 1) (tail xs))


map :: (a -> b) -> Stream a -> Stream b
map f xs = f (head xs) :& map f (tail xs)


zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> Stream a -> Stream b -> Stream c
zipWith f xs ys = f (head xs) (head ys) :& zipWith f (tail xs) (tail ys)


iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> Stream a
iterate f a = a :& iterate f (f a)
```

Now I want to declare instance of Num class for my type.

```
instance P.Num a => P.Num (Stream a) where
  (+)         xs ys  = zipWith (+) xs ys
  (-)         xs ys  = zipWith (-) xs ys
  (*)         xs ys  = zipWith (*) xs ys
  negate      xs     = map P.negate xs
  abs         xs     = map P.abs xs
  signum      xs     = map P.signum xs
  fromInteger x      = P.error "Not implemented yet" --constStream x
```

Functions `*`, `-`, `*` work as I want, but functions `negate`, `abs` and `signum` don't exist.

```
GHCi, version 8.2.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :l Stream
[1 of 1] Compiling Stream           ( Stream.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Stream> s1 = iterate (\x -> x + 1) 1
*Stream> negate s1

<interactive>:3:1: error:
    • Variable not in scope: negate :: Stream P.Integer -> t
    • Perhaps you meant ‘P.negate’ (imported from Prelude)
```

Comment: Well yes, because you didn't `import Prelude (negate)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GHCi tries to provide the same access to bindings as if we were inside the module we load. Since the module has explicit `Prelude` imports

```
import Prelude ((+), (-), (<), (++), (*), otherwise, id)
import qualified Prelude as P
```

then GHCi also requires the user to type `P.negate`. After all, the module source code requires that as well.

In GHCi, I guess one can also `import Prelude` so to have all the bindings available again, without having to qualify them with `P.`.